# Custom route breaks Default routing Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have custom routing for controller added right over the default one:

Custom:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "FaqSubCategory",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{TapCode}",
            defaults: new { controller = "FAQ", action = "GetChosenFaqSubCategory", TapCode = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = new CultureConstraint() }
        );
```

Custom v2:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "FaqSubCategory",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{TapCode}",
            defaults: new { controller = "FAQ", action = "GetChosenFaqSubCategory", TapCode = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = new CultureConstraint(), FAQ = new TranslateControllersConstraint("4189") }
        );
```

Default:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultWithCulture",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{ID}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", ID = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = new CultureConstraint() }
        );
```

Basically because of that custom route, home page is receiving "/home/index" and some of the other pages are receiving "/index" at the end of the URL

When I write the custom routing like the second variant, then everything is working perfectly except the FAQ controller.

Answer (score 0):

When an MVC application first starts it creates the route table.The default route table contains a single route named Default. So default route should have Default name, instead of DefaultWithCulture an your default route should have default culture

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
             url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{ID}",
            defaults: new { culture="en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", ID = UrlParameter.Optional },
            .....
```